# Why my android emulator is not working in vs code?

Tags: android, react-native

Why my emolator is not working in vs code

I try npx start and npx run android but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

**Configure the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable**

**macOS:**

Add the following lines to your `$HOME/.bash_profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc` (if you are using zsh then `~/.zprofile` or `~/.zshrc`) config file:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

**windows:**

[image]

Reference:

[Environment SetUp](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)